# Spring cant find classpath resource--->class path resource cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: spring

Spring cant find classpath resource.(welcomeUser.xml)

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("welcomeUser.xml");
```

welcomeUser.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="welcomeUserBean" class="bean.WelcomeUserBean">  
<property name="happyHourService">       
    <ref bean="happyHourService"/>        
</property>
<property name="standardService">       
    <ref bean="standardService"/>             
</property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [../welcomeUser.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [../welcomeUser.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209).....................................
```

Cant get rid of this exception....need help

Comment: The location is not correct in your Java code. What is the structure of your application and where is that .xml file located?

Comment: @AndreiStefan yes xml file location was wrong..thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to load "welcomeUser.xml" with a class path style, so make sure where is your "welcomeUser.xml"? if it's under WEB-INF or WEB-INF/classes, please use:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/welcomeUser.xml");
```

If it's not there, please tell me, let me tell you how to write the path!